# How can I set the default permissions for new files in a directory?

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a local directory /var/foo

I'd like it so that any file created in here can be read and written by any user (and any directory can be rwx).

I've tried `chacl -b u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rw- u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /var/foo`

and then when I run `getfacl /var/foo` it seems these permissions are there, but then I can't even ls  /var/foo any more.

There are no existing files or directories in there, but there are going to be, and I need to make sure they are world-write and -readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in `man setfacl` you set default ACLs by prepending them with `default:`.

```
setfacl -m default:u::rwx,default:g::rwx /var/foo
```

Comment: Usage: setfacl [-bkndRLP] { -m|-M|-x|-X ... } file ...

Comment: Should have been `setfacl -m ...`, @Blazemore.

Comment: @grawity Indeed. I mistakenly skipped the `-m` when posting my answer. Thanks for fixing.